# jumping form Java to C

Tags: java, c++, lwjgl

Ok I gave been playing around with java for a year now an I can say that is is in my power to write a fully functional program.

A month ago I started studying vectors and so, when I tempted to implementing them into the LWJGL I realized that Java is not fast enough for the level of graphics that I wish to generate.

Now that is my problem and I have decided that I must learn a stronger Language but where do I begin I have tinkered around in C/C++ before but it kills my ambition to go and start over after already using a hole year.

my "algors" for rendering a vector are:

z = r(cos t+j sin t) //where the t is degrees and r is its length
(for the curious)

the program the continues a loop that alters its length with 1, gets its end X and Y and draws a pixel on that spot.

Not for game coding.

Name 1 free E-Book that will get Me on My feet with C

Comment: Stack is for specific programming questions. Maybe try programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: "Java is not fast enough for the level of graphics that I wish to generate" - I'd be very surprised if that was true nowadays?

Comment: So what is the question? How to learn C or C++? First pick one of them, maybe get a book on which ever you pick, and then start playing around. That is, the exact same thing you did to learn Java, right?

Comment: It may be that your algorithms are not efficient enough to generate high level graphics with java.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't let having to learn a second language discourage you - most programmers know more than just one language, and in fact C++ makes a good second language, in my opinion. Still, I don't really see what question you are asking, and without knowing what you want to do it is hard to advise you where to start. Get a good book, _then_ have a look at a few tutorials (there's quite a lot of good ones out there, but a lot of bad ones too)

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian the programmers mods would eat you for your general "bad questions go on programmers" stance.

Comment: @djechlin I wasn't aware I had a stance on the issue.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian well, I'm informing you. Avoid suggesting that questions that are bad on any SE site go on programmers.SE. They're no more opinion to opinion-based questions than SO is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I realized that Java is not fast enough for the level of graphics that I wish to generate.

Java is plenty fast. Unless you want to work with high performance graphics, you can use it safely (and you will probably be able to use it even with high performance graphics).

In the vast majority of cases, the speed of your application will be a function of algorithmic complexity, not language used.

After your application is completed, if it doesn't run fast enough, you can optimize. If it still doesn't run fast enough, you can implement critical parts in C/C++/your-language-here.

If you start from "the language is not fast enough", you're already doing it wrong.

Comment: the problem is  that in essence my math draws 36 000 dots on the screen and the rendering loop has trouble to get to all of them,*sigh*,might I ask where I am to start if I am to intensify my study of C/C++

Comment: @WilliamGourley Drawing 36000 dots one by one will take a while in any language.

Comment: @WilliamGourley `"If you start from "the language is not fast enough", you're already doing it wrong."` Please believe us, your issue is **NOT** the programming language.

Comment: @Hulk ok than you you gave me a brain wave(scale down the resolution so that the data is not lost but a zoom is still possible)

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus may I ask what I can do better because I am unable to draw advanced shapes without lag or a dotty mess. not sarcastic but honest

Comment: _"scale down the resolution so that the data is not lost but a zoom is still possible"_ - It sounds like you could use a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Draw each quadrant at a different detail level based on the zoom level and what parts are visible.

Comment: @Hulk I can onley do 2D at the moment

Comment: @Hulk I don't know how to do that

Comment: @Hulk no but remember that this is done in the LWJGL display

Comment: @WilliamGourley oh, indeed, I didn't notice that yet. So you're already using a game library capable of doing 3D Graphics in GL and everything. In that case, after just a quick look at the docs of the library I recommend using a single (slim) quad for representing a line

Comment: @Hulk I am but a noob and need guidance as how to thoroughly use the LWJGL to its full potential.

Comment: @WilliamGourley have a look at [the lwjgl docs](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=The_Quad_with_Projection,_View_and_Model_matrices) for how to position and rotate quads. If you have more questions, please ask a new question (this is already too long for comments)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write a game, use an engine. There are many great engines in many languages. If you wonder about language-inherent performance, and you try to solve technological issues yourself, you are gonna be stuck doing that forever.

Do not reinvent the wheel. Stop worrying about which programming language is the best fit, and rather think about which engine is best suited for what you want to make.